# Sorting through list of strings using selection sort, but not by the first elements (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, selection-sort

I have a list of strings which include names and identification numbers that looks like this:
['AARON VASS [ID:100492465]', 'ABRAHAM STROEBEL [ID:100435684]', 'ABRAM BIRKMAIER [ID:100542192]'

I want to sort them based on the identification numbers using selection sort. So far, I have the code which does selection sort, and it sorts by alphabetical, by I am just unsure about what I need to alter in order to sort by the numbers instead.
My code so far:
def sort_students_by_id(student_list):

```
for index in range(len(student_list)):
    minPos = index
    for pos in range(index+1, len(student_list)):
        if student_list[pos] < student_list[minPos]:
            minPos = pos
    tmp = student_list[index]
    student_list[index] = student_list[minPos]
    student_list[minPos] = tmp
return student_list
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
A = ['AARON VASS [ID:100492465]', 'ABRAHAM STROEBEL [ID:100435684]', 'ABRAM BIRKMAIER [ID:100542192]']
B = sorted(A, key = lambda x: x.split()[-1][4:-1])
```